# Getting quarterly forward rates with QuantLib

Tags: quantlib, forward-rate

I am trying to build a quarterly forward curve with 3 month USD Libor swap rates from 1Y to 50Y as inputs.

From other posts I have looked at, I have managed to come up with this code so far:

```
terms =['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8',
 '9', '10', '12', '15', '20', '25', '30', '40', '50']
rate = [0.17, 0.17800000000000002,  0.244,  0.364,  0.499,
 0.6409999999999999,  0.773,  0.887,  0.987,  1.074,  1.214, 1.355, 
1.4809999999999999, 1.5390000000000001, 1.567,
 1.527, 1.45]

LIBOR= ql.IborIndex('USDLibor', ql.Period('3M'), 2, ql.USDCurrency(), ql.UnitedStates(), ql.ModifiedFollowing,  True, ql.Actual360()) 
helpers = [] # Helpers

helpers.append( ql.DepositRateHelper(0, ql.USDLibor(ql.Period('50Y'))))  # changed from one year 
helpers.append( ql.SwapRateHelper(0.06, ql.UsdLiborSwapIsdaFixAm(ql.Period('3m')))
)


curve = ql.PiecewiseLogCubicDiscount(0, ql.TARGET(), helpers, day_count)
curve.enableExtrapolation()

all_days = ql.MakeSchedule(
    curve.referenceDate(),
    curve.maxDate(),
    ql.Period('3M')
)

rates_fwd = [
    curve.forwardRate(d, calendar.advance(d,90,ql.Days), day_count, ql.Simple).rate()
    for d in all_days
]
```

Not sure if the code above is correct, but it seems to work. The problem is that it's not using my input terms and rate. Anyone know how a way around this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code is not really correct, because you are only supplying two instruments: a 50Y Deposit with a rate of 0% and a 3m swap with a rate of 6%.

If you plot your fwd rates, this is what you'll see:

[image]

What you want to do is supply a helper for each of your swaps. Then QuantLib will bootstrap the discount factors for the nodes you supplied and interpolate the log discount factors using the chosen method (`PiecewiseLogCubicDiscount`) for values that are not curve nodes.

Here is a working example:

```
import QuantLib as ql
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

terms =['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8',
 '9', '10', '12', '15', '20', '25', '30', '40', '50']
rate = [0.17, 0.17800000000000002,  0.244,  0.364,  0.499,
 0.6409999999999999,  0.773,  0.887,  0.987,  1.074,  1.214, 1.355, 
1.4809999999999999, 1.5390000000000001, 1.567,
 1.527, 1.45]

index = ql.USDLibor(ql.Period('3M'))
helpers = []
dc = ql.Actual360()

for term, r in zip(terms, rate):
    swapIndex = ql.UsdLiborSwapIsdaFixAm(ql.Period(int(term), ql.Years))
    helpers.append(ql.SwapRateHelper(r/100, swapIndex))
    
curve = ql.PiecewiseLogCubicDiscount(0, ql.TARGET(), helpers, dc)
curve.enableExtrapolation()

days = ql.MakeSchedule(curve.referenceDate(), curve.maxDate(), ql.Period('3M'))
fwds = [
    curve.forwardRate(d, ql.UnitedStates().advance(d,90,ql.Days), dc, ql.Simple).rate()
    for d in days
]

plt.plot([dt.to_date() for dt in days], fwds)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks David! Worked a charm!

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked through Gautham's excellent tutorial on term structures in quantlib python: http://gouthamanbalaraman.com/blog/quantlib-term-structure-bootstrap-yield-curve.html? You can then modify his code to build any other kind of term structure (eg. swap...etc).

Comment: Thanks, will take a look!